# How to get value from carousel which is active?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using reactive forms, when submitting a form I want to send the carousel's active item as a value.
how can I achieve that?

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-on4rq3?file=app/app.component.ts)

**.ts**

```
this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
    this._formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ["", Validators.required],
      lastName: ["", Validators.required],
      Age: ["", Validators.required]
    })
  ])
});
```

**.html**

```
  <input matInput formControlName="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
  <input matInput formControlName="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>

  <p>Select Age</p>
  <carousel height="100%" width="120" cellsToShow="1" overflowCellsLimit="3" id="age">
    <div class="carousel-cell" *ngFor="let year of years">
      {{year.year}}Years
    </div>
  </carousel>
  <button style="margin-top: 4rem;" mat-button matStepperNext (click)="onSubmit()" class="next">Submit <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.ts` file add a new property named `myCarousel` with a `@ViewChild` decorator like below:

```
@ViewChild("myCarousel") myCarousel: CarouselComponent;
```

Now, add a reference to the `myCarousel` in your html file like below:

```
<carousel #myCarousel height="100%" width="120" cellsToShow="1" overflowCellsLimit="3" id="age">
    <div class="carousel-cell" *ngFor="let year of years">
       {{year.year}}Years
    </div>
</carousel>
```

Next in your `onSubmit` method you could get the current activate slide by using `this.myCarousel.slideCounter` like below

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.formGroup.value);
  console.log(this.myCarousel.slideCounter + 1)
}
```

The `slideCounter` property start its counting from 0 and that's why I have added `+1`
I have tested it in stackblitz. Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Now i want to set that value as my Age formcontrol value. i used setvalue but its empty when i submit it. i updated my stackblitz

Comment: What is empty? Setting the Age formcontrol value seems fine to me. Are you talking about the form which you're passing to your service?

Comment: when i submit a form Age value is empty string

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Are you trying to set the value visibile in the slider as Age value?

Comment: Yes! I used setValue in my stackblitz as you can see but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry! but I could see that your AgeValue form control has a value based upon the slide value. Just console the `AgeValue` and `this.formGroup`. You will be able to see the age

Comment: Hey! how can i use this on valueChanges method? i want to call api method on every inputs valueChanges, but it doesn't works on carousel.

Comment: I am not sure whether you can use valueChanges method on carousel. I don't see any method as such in their documentation. Yes if you could bind your carousel with form control then you can use valueChanges for that carousel form control.